# How to extract id from url ? Google sheet

Tags: java, string, url, google-sheets-api

I have the follow urls.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY/edit#gid=1842172258
https://docs.google.com/a/example.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6PTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY/edit#gid=1842172258
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY
```

Foreach url, I need to extract the sheet id: `1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6PTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY` into a java String.

I am thinking of using **split** but it can't work with all test cases:

```
String string = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY/edit#gid=1842172258";
String[] parts = string.split("/");
String res = parts[parts.length-2];
Log.d("hello res",res );
```

How can I that be possible?

Comment: Does the ID always follow /spreadsheets/d/?  If so, then you can write a regex that looks for /spreadsheets/d/ and then captures the component following that.  You don't need to use `split`.  You could still use `split` and search for array elements that equal "spreadsheets" and "d".  If there are other cases where the ID doesn't follow this, you'll have to figure out what the possibilities are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the id you are looking for always follow "/spreadsheets/d/" if it is the case you can update your code to that

```
        String string = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY/edit#gid=1842172258";
        String[] parts = string.split("spreadsheets/d/");
        String result;
        if(parts[1].contains("/")){
            String[] parts2 = parts[1].split("/");
            result = parts2[0];
        }
        else{
            result=parts[1];
        }
        System.out.println("hello "+ result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use regex `\/d\/(.*?)(\/|$)` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X9iFHN/1)) to solve your problem, if you look closer you can see that the ID exist between `d/` and `/` or `end of line` for that you can get every thing between this, check this code demo :

```
String[] urls = new String[]{
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY/edit#gid=1842172258",
    "https://docs.google.com/a/example.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6PTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY/edit#gid=1842172258",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY"
};

String regex = "\\/d\\/(.*?)(\\/|$)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String url : urls) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

**Outputs**

```
1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY
1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6PTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY
1mrsetjgfZI2BIypz7SGHMOfHGv6kTKTzY0xOM5c6TXY
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using regex**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\/d\\/)[^\\/]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

**Using Java**

```
String result = url.substring(url.indexOf("/d/") + 3);
int slash = result.indexOf("/");
result =  slash == -1 ? result
                      : result.substring(0, slash);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google use fixed lenght characters for its IDs, in your case they are 44 characters and these are the characters google use: alphanumeric, -, and _  so you can use this regex:

```
regex = "([\w-]){44}"
match = re.search(regex,url)
```